# How to add score to kivy game

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy and trying to add a score to it. My game is a soccer juggling game, so whenever I click on the soccer ball I want the score to increase by 1. I currently have a code that increases the score by one when I click on the "start game" button. How can I make it so that "on_touch_down" the score increases by 1? Below is my code!

main.py

```
class Ball(Image):
velocity = NumericProperty(0)


def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Soccer ball sound.wav')
        sound.play()
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
        self.velocity = 275
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)


def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)


class MainApp(App):
    GRAVITY = 300


def move_ball(self, time_passed):
    ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
    ball.y = ball.y + ball.velocity * time_passed
    ball.velocity = ball.velocity - self.GRAVITY * time_passed


def start_game(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_ball, 1/60.)
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = #same line
    str(int(self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text) + 1) #same line
```

gamescreen.kv

```
        Label:
        id: score
        size_hint: None, None
        font_size: dp(25)
        font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
        text: "0"
        color: "gold"
        pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.9}

    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        font_size: dp(20)
        font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
        text: "Start Game"
        color: "gold"
        pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
        size: 150, 55
        size_hint: None, None
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (57/255.0, 179/255.0, 242/255.0, .10)


        on_release:
            self.disabled = True
            self.opacity = 0
            root.play_sound()
            app.start_game()


    Ball:
        source: "icons/ball.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 500
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        id: ball
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python kivy updating game score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253667/python-kivy-updating-game-score)

Comment: Yes that helped!